# How To Get "Find Usages" working with implicit operator methods?

Tags: c#, .net, operators, implicit

I never liked implicit operators (prefer extension methods) because it is hard to see visually when that cast/conversion happens in the code.

Imagine if you have example like below:

```
public static implicit operator Deal(string dealAsXml)
{
    //convert the xml into Deal object
}
```

Above implicit operator helps you to cast/convert deal in Xml format into Deal Object.

Usually when you right click on a method, you can use "Find Usages" (or Alt+F7) on it, which is quite helpful, is there anything similar for implicit operators ?

I think that's another reason to use the Extensions methods where possible.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

EDIT FROM THE FUTURE: Current versions of Visual Studio let you right-click "Find All References" on implicit operators. Right click on the conversion type (`Deal` in this example) or operator symbol (`+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, etc.) to access the "Find All References" command. So the below advice is now `[Obsolete]`

---

Maybe something like Resharper can do it, but I'm not sure.  When I need to find usages, I do it the poor-man's way and remove the implicit operator, recompile and find the errors.

I suppose theoretically the compiler might then miss a case if it can use a different implicit operator (or switch to an "object" type overload of a method), but it tends to work for my usages.  I'm sure there's a better solution, but it's worked for me so far.

EDIT: Just had a thought and tested it.  Marking your implicit operator as `[Obsolete]` will actually result in a compiler warning wherever you use it!  I suppose this will catch those corner cases where there are other valid overloads that you'd miss having removed the implicit operator altogether.

Comment: Resharper does not find usages of implicit operators either.

Comment: done the same poor man's way as well. :) which is quite daunting if you have huge solution

Comment: That's too bad.  You'd think there'd be a way since the implicit operators (I believe) are statically compiled and would be easily discoverable like any static method.

Comment: Marking the implicit operator as `[Obsolete]` works even better as it should catch the other overload cases.

Comment: that is a good one Chris, that way you can at least get warning (without breaking the build). will wait if anyone else comes up with better idea.

Comment: For sure; I'd like to know if there's a way to have it check/report through the standard `Find Symbol Results` window if only to have consistency in workflow and not have to alter code.  Especially in the case when you're looking in 3rd party libraries where you can't exactly add the obsolete attribute yourself.