# Finding where a method is called for a convention test

Tags: c#, tdd, convention, roslyn

I'm trying to write a convention test that specifies that a method should only be called in some contexts - specifically I have a static `Empty` getter that I only want to allow used in test methods, vis methods decorated with `TestAttribute`.

I know that I should also mark the getter as obsolete, use another method etc, but I also want a convention test around this so it doesn't break in the future.

I am guessing I want to use static analysis through reflection in my convention test. How would I go about performing this kind of analysis?

Comment: Reflection won't provide implementation details (body) of your methods. You should use something similar to Roslyn. I suggest to add tag `roslyn` to your question, so that you will receive help from it's team, as Eric Lippert did with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891197/finding-everywhere-an-enum-is-converted-to-string

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Roslyn can help with this sort of thing.  An example of what this might look like as a standalone analysis would be something like:

```
var solution = Solution.Load(pathToSolution);
foreach (var project in solution.Projects)
{
    var type = project.GetCompilation().GetTypeByMetadataName(typeNameContainingMethod);
    var method = type.GetMembers("Empty").Single();
    var references = method.FindAllReferences(solution);
    foreach (var referencedSymbol in references)
    {
        foreach (var referenceLocation in references)
        {
            CheckIfCallIsAllowed(referenceLocation);
        }
    }
}
```

You might also look at the Creating a Code Issue walkthrough and the Code Issue template that comes with the Roslyn CTP for another approach to doing this at edit time, instead of in a test.